# Error on creating LaserScan message using Sonar data

Tags: laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a laserscan using Sonar Sensor but I got an error launching the file.

```
[serial.launch] is neither a launch file in package [name] nor is [name] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I checked the files if there are some typographical errors or files are in a wrong path but everything is okay.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278286/error-on-creating-laserscan-message-using-sonar-data/) by [sonarsensor](https://answers.ros.org/users/32948/sonarsensor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-12-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-12-29**:
Have you sourced your environment?

**Comment by [sonarsensor](https://answers.ros.org/users/32948/sonarsensor/) on 2018-01-02**:
Yes, I did the setup.bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package should most probably not be called `name` but rather `serial`.

From the error output, it seems your command was

```
roslaunch name serial.launch
```

The Syntax is

```
roslaunch <pkg> <Launch file>
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0